# Neo4j Cypher script freezes for too many nodes

Tags: neo4j

I have a database with about 300,000 nodes. For comparison purposes with a previous database version, I need to get all the nodes and the number of nodes connected to it or it is connected to.

My cypher query looks like this:

`match (node)-[r]-(n) return node.Name, count(n)`

And my expected result looks like this:

**Name  |  Count**

Node1  | 8

Node2  | 3

Node3  | 5

I'm testing this on Neo4j's web interface (`version 3.0.3`). For some reason the web interface freezes maybe because of the number of results that I'm getting back so definitely this is a performance issue of the query.

[image]

Can this query still be optimized?

Comment: Have you try to runt this query in the shell (`bin/neo4j-shell ` ) instead of the browser ?

Comment: @logisima no, but I will

Comment: 300k lines are too much for the web interface. Try loading it with a script/program and save it to a file or something.

Comment: Just ran my query in the web interface with 1826853 rows just fine.

Comment: @manonthemat with the same query?

Comment: @logisima it works fine on my C# code

Answer (score 0):

This is faster, has less dbhits and will also give you node names of unconnected nodes (if you want).

`MATCH (node) RETURN node.Name, size((node)-[]-())`

Comment: same thing it freezes